# Cannot implicitly convert type System.Linq.IQueryable to System Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

Tags: c#, linq, generics

I have this linq query which will select all the records in my table InventoryLocation. however it gives me an error... I dunno what is the problem... I'm really new to this so bear with me...

**Error**

> Cannot implicitly convert type System.Linq.IQueryable to System
>   Collections.Generic.IEnumerable

thanks in advance..

```
 public IEnumerable<InventoryLocationModel> GetInventoryLocations()
    {
        IEnumerable<InventoryLocationModel> results = null;

        using (DataContext ctx = new DataContext())
        {
            results = from a in ctx.InventoryLocations select a;
        }

        return results;
    }
```

Comment: Try : `results = (from a in ctx.InventoryLocations select a).AsEnumerable<InventoryLocationModel>();`

Comment: What is the return type of your `DataContext.InventoryLocations`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is that you aren't actually executing the query so you are left with just the IQueryable instead of actual results, thus you are getting the error.

```
public IEnumerable<InventoryLocationModel> GetInventoryLocations()
{
    IEnumerable<InventoryLocationModel> results = null;

    using (DataContext ctx = new DataContext())
    {
        results = (from a in ctx.InventoryLocations select a).ToList();
    }

    return results;
}
```

You can also simplify your query. All you really need for what you are doing is

```
public IEnumerable<InventoryLocationModel> GetInventoryLocations()
{
    using (DataContext ctx = new DataContext())
    {
        return ctx.InventoryLocations.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: so there's no error?... I just have to execute the method?

Comment: No, there is an error. You are trying to assign an `IQueryable` to an `IEnumerable`, but there is no implicit conversion defined between the two types, hence why you are getting an implicit cast compiler error.

Comment: For an EF query to actually run, you need to actualize the data somehow. The main ones you'll see used are `ToList()`, `First()`, `FirstOrDefault()`, `Single()`, and `SingleOrDefault()`. There are others, but in my experience those are the most used ones.

Comment: `ToList()` executes the query eagerly, which may not be desired, especially since the method is returning `IEnumerable`. Better to defer execution further up the call chain and let the caller decide.

Comment: @ShiguriAnemone' It's clear that you're not showing us your full code. There is no way `ToList` is causing the same error (casting `IQueryable` to `IEnumerable`). Either you're getting the error in a *different* location, or you've misunderstood Bradford's solution.

Answer (score 2):

This will get what you want:

```
results = (from a in ctx.InventoryLocations select a).AsEnumerable();
```

This ensures that you still take advantage of LINQ's [deferred execution](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/linq/750/deferred-vs-immediate-query-execution-linq).

Comment: @ShiguriAnemone' I've reproduced the entire code block in Visual Studio with no issue. Are you sure the error is coming from this routine?

Comment: yes sir... it still got an error on this line... same error

Comment: @ShiguriAnemone' You're not telling us the whole story, then. There is no cast in Rex's answer, so I find it difficult to believe you're getting an error related to an invalid cast.